# Increase Parent Flatlist Item Height w.r.t child flatlist in Nested flatlist in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to create a nested Flatlist(Flatlist inside another Flatlist), with dynamic data that is fetched from webservices.

Once the inner flatlist data gets fetched, basing on the content I am trying to increase the parent flatlist item height.

Can somebody guide me to solve the problem

The below is the view I am working 
[image: NestedFlatList View]

From App.js

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    if (item.empty === true) {
      return <View style={[styles.item, styles.itemInvisible]} />;
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text style={styles.itemText}>Name</Text>
        <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.key}</Text>

        <InnerListView updateHeight={this.updateHeight} />
      </View>

    );
  };

render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={[
          { key: 'ABCDEFGH' }
        ]}
        style={styles.container}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        numColumns={numColumns}
      />
    );
  }
```

From InnerList

```
find_dimesions(layout){
        const {x, y, width, height} = layout;
        console.warn("xpos"+ x);
        console.warn("ypos"+y);
        console.warn("width"+width);
        console.warn("height"+height);
        this.props.updateHeight(height)
      }

    renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
        if (item.empty === true) {
            return (<View style={[styles.item, styles.itemInvisible]} />);
        }
        return (
            <View style={styles.item}>
                <Text style={styles.itemText}>Name</Text>
                <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.key}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    };

render() {
        return (
              <FlatList
              onLayout={(event) => { this.find_dimesions(event.nativeEvent.layout) }}
                data={formatData(data, numColumns)}
                style={styles.container}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                numColumns={numColumns}
              />
        );
    }
```

I am expecting the parent view i.e redView height need to be increased.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, an FYI: you could create this exact layout with a single SectionList as well if you want.

But to answer your question to get the outer flatlist to update its content / layout when the inner gets updated, you could make use of the extraData prop from FlatList. This prop allows the FlatList to update once its value changes. So the extraData you provide to the outer FlatList should be the same as the data for the inner FlatList.